# Dendrogram and heatmap on similarity matrix

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have already computed a similarity matrix for pairwise comparisons of my data, and I want to use hierarchical clustering and a heatmap to visualize the data.

The heatmap isn't an issue, but for the hierarchical clustering, it seems to be doing a distance matrix of my similarity matrix (I am using package `aheatmap` if that changes things), and then clustering.

What is the best way to specify that it is already a similarity matrix and cluster based on that data, next to the figure of the heatmap?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you saying you pass your similarity matrix into the `pheatmap` function to do another similarity matrix? I wouldn't think that could work. Can't you just do that in the function, specifying what type of distance method you want? Can you clarify if I'm not correct in my assumptions?

Comment: No, I want to prevent the package from creating a similarity matrix from the similarity matrix I am already passing into it. If I am mistaken that it isn't actually doing that, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify your pairs to `aheatmap`. I tried it out with the `iris` package.

```
NMF::aheatmap(iris[, 3:4]) # The default uses euclidean
NMF::aheatmap(iris[, 3:4], Rowv = 'manhattan', Colv = 'euclidean') # Specify what type of distance method to use on rows, and columns.
```

It also says you can pass external clustering to it. See the ?NMF::aheatmap help file for more.

```
hc <- hclust(dist(x, method = 'minkowski'), method = 'centroid')
aheatmap(x, Rowv = hc, info = TRUE)
```